# Step-by-step derivative of $\frac{(2x)^{bx}}{(x + a)^{bx}}$

Tags: derivatives

Can someone please walk step by step on how to calculate the derivative

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{(2x)^{bx}}{(x + a)^{bx}}$

Where $a$ and $b$ can be thought of as constants.
And we can assume $a,b, x > 0$.

Comment: Let $y=\frac{(2x)^{bx}}{(x+a)^{bx}}$ ... take logarithms ... differentiate

Comment: That's quite a change there.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX ... You solution was sound! ... you should roll back the edit !

Comment: You should ask a new question since it was such a massive change from what you had and leave what you originally had.

Comment: Sorry for the change, I just realized my issue was something else. @AlgorithmsX, thanks so much for your solution, it seems like something similar could be applied here and I really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX, ok, I can do that.

Comment: @user341502 I made a mistake, so let me fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting as $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(2-\frac{2a}{x+a}\right)^{bx}$$
We use $x^n=e^{n\ln x}$ to rewrite this as
$$\frac{d}{dx}\exp\left(bx\ln\left(2-\frac{2a}{x+a}\right)\right)$$
From there, we use the Chain Rule with $f(g)=e^g$ and $g(x)=bx\ln\left(2-\frac{2a}{x+a}\right)$. $f'(g)=e^g$. From there, we use the Product Rule to find
$$g'(x)=b\ln\left(2-\frac{2a}{x+a}\right)+2abx\left(2-\frac{2a}{x+a}\right)^{-1}(x+a)^{-2}$$
in which we used the Chain Rule again with $u(v)=\ln v$ and $v(x)=\left(2-\frac{2a}{x+a}\right)$. From there, we can see that the result is
$$e^{g(x)}\cdot g'(x)=\left(2-\frac{2a}{x+a}\right)^{bx}\cdot b\ln\left(2-\frac{2a}{x+a}\right)+bx\left(2-\frac{2a}{x+a}\right)^{-1}(x+a)^{-2}$$

Comment: Are you sure the final answer is correct? Or perhaps my answer is wrong.

Comment: @mrnovice Your answer is correct. I messed up when I defined $f(g)=g^{bx}$, which does not define $f(g)$ in terms of $g$. I decided to do it a different way.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using the quotient rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)= \frac{g(x)f'(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}$$

So we have a function $$h(x) = \frac{(2x)^{bx}}{(x+a)^{bx}},\quad f(x) =(2x)^{bx},\quad g(x) = (x+a)^{bx}$$

Then $$h'(x) =  \frac{(x+a)^{bx}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left((2x)^{bx}\right)-(2x)^{bx}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left((x+a)^{bx}\right)}{((x+a)^{bx})^2}$$

Consider $y=(2x)^{bx}$

$\implies \ln y = bx\ln (2x)$

We also have the product rule which says $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x)) = f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$

Differentiating with respect to $x$:

$\implies \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} = b\cdot\ln(2x)+bx\cdot \frac{2}{2x} = b(\ln2x+1)$

Then $\frac{dy}{dx} = (2x)^{bx}\cdot b(\ln 2x+1)$

Now consider $u = (x+a)^{bx}$

$\ln u = bx\ln(x+a)$

$\frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{dx} = b\ln(x+a)+bx\cdot \frac{1}{x+a}$

$\frac{du}{dx} = b(x+a)^{bx}(\ln(x+a)+\frac{x}{x+a})$

So we now have the derivatives of $(2x)^{bx}$ and $(x+a)^{bx}$, so we can plug them into our formula for $h'(x)$.

$$h'(x) = \frac{(x+a)^{bx}\cdot (2x)^{bx}\cdot b(\ln 2x+1) -(2x)^{bx}\cdot b(x+a)^{bx}(\ln(x+a)+\frac{x}{x+a})}{(x+a)^{2bx}}$$

$$h'(x) = \frac{b(x+a)^{bx}\cdot (2x)^{bx}(\ln(2x+1)-\ln(x+a)-\frac{x}{x+a})}{(x+a)^{2bx}}$$

$$h'(x) = \frac{b(2x)^{bx}}{(x+a)^{bx}}\left(\ln\left(\frac{2x+1}{x+1}\right)-\frac{x}{x+a}\right)$$

Comment: You could have take logarithms at the start & used $\frac{2x}{x+a}=2-\frac{2a}{x+a}$ (as AlgorithmX did) ...that would have made it a little easier.